# InstallShield Error -6636 - File Keys Error

Tags: crystal-reports, installshield

This error occurred when I tried to build a single EXE image with InstallShield 12 Premium:

> ISDEV : error -6636: The file key
>   Global_VC_CPPRT60_f0.51D569E3_8A28_11D2_B962_006097C4DE24 and
>   Global_VC_CPPRT60_f0.51D569E3_8A28_11D2_B962_006097C4DE24 are found in
>   the File table. Despite having different cases, the identical key
>   names will cause an unexpected result when the files are installed on
>   the target system. This occurs because the compressed files in the
>   cabinet file are named using the file keys. To correct this issue,
>   change one of the file keys to be unique in the cabinet file if you
>   are building a compressed setup or a merge module. You can change the
>   file key name in the Direct Editor view.

The user is left with virtually no clue as to what to do.

After extensive research, I discovered the answer, which follows.

Answer (score 0):

The root of this issue lies in this file:
CrystalReports8.5CrystalReportAPI.Msm
or possibly in this file:
CyrstalReports85_Crpre32.msm

These files typically are located here:
C:\Program Files\Macrovision\IS12\Modules\i386

If you open either of the above msm (merge file) in InstallShield, you will see that it contains two Dependencies:
MSVCIRT.DLL (Version 6.0.8168.0) - Microsoft C++ Runtime Library I/O 6.0
MSVCP60.DLL (Version 6.0.8168.0) - Microsoft C++ Runtime Library 6.0

If you examine the details of each entry, you will see that BOTH contain the same Module ID:
MSVCP60.51D569E3_8A28_11D2_B962_006097C4DE24

Because the goal of the merge file is to install CRPE32.DLL for Crystal Reports 8.5, one solution is to remove this merge file from your installation script and install it as a file rather than as a merge module. [The merge module might be cited in one of the branches in the Installation Designer--such as Organization | Setup Design, and/or it might appear under Organization | Components.]

On the other hand, if you accidentally left references to the above redistributable in your project (if you're unsure, check InstallShield's Install Designer | Organization | Setup Design and Install Designer | Application Data | Redistributables for references to CrystalReports8.5CrystalReportAPI.Msm), then you simply need to remove them from your InstallShield project before attempting to rebuild.